# What are the best answers to the interview question "why are you choosing to return to this role/work?" when re-entering after taking a break?

Tags: job-search, job-change, career-switch, motivation, break-time

Update - I've edited the question to serve the broader community. New here and please excuse me for the initial rookie errors.

I'm re-entering corporate full-time workforce after ~4 years of taking a break to study and setup my own small practice. I learnt a lot trying to run a small business on my own, but I'm now wanting to go back to full time work as
a) I don't feel like running a business anymore and want to work in a team
b) Income was very low and I need a full-time job to get back on track and make up for lost time.
c) I genuinely want to focus on my long term career. Happy I tried doing something on my own but don't think it's for me.

Question: How can I confidently explain the reasons why I now want full-time work, in a way that companies would like to hear and doesn't just sound like "I'm coming back because I want to work full-time and get an income"?

I've mentioned reasons like - I want to focus on my full-time career going forward and this company and role are great because values align, role scope fits my experience + challenges me to learn more, and get to work in the area I'm passionate about.. but one of the recruiters gave feedback to think of other high-level reasons why I'm returning to work. This has left me a bit puzzled.

Comment: How were you doing it during the ten years +?

Comment: First steps always the hardest after that it takes care of itself somehow

Comment: "deep demotivation" lol! Ok, well, I found that the tools had gotten better after I returned to programming, and the people I worked with were unexpectedly nice and supportive, and the customer base was one I cared about serving. The right job found me and I was pleased. If I had needed to search again, I would have. I am sure your dread will dissipate. Good luck!

Comment: Ha ha, thank you HI for validating that emotion. It's painful to motivate and pull ourselves back up again n again during a job hunt. Thanks for sharing your story, happy for you and looks like I need to have a positive mindset and not lose hope and keep searching. Hoping to find my right job, soon too.

Comment: Thank you Kilisi... I'll remember that! 

Comment: I think, money in terms of savings and helping family in need & some lifestyle desires. Recognition in terms of effort put in all these years, studies done & a tiny bit of envy/inspiration when I see peers in higher jobs.

Comment: Taking the break and not getting back sooner has probably caused the confidence to dip creating self-doubt. I quit the last company due to burnout, very little support and was blamed for the whole thing because they hadn't planned personnel better, even though I did everything right as an employee.

Comment: Ok, so you're traumatized. The word is overused, but still, it has a meaning. It's like an injured area that remains sensitive after healing. What happened was not the norm, be willing to try again. I'm not a therapist, but they can be really helpful.

Comment: In these situations, do you have a group of friends and/or family that can encourage you and be positive/motivational to you?  If not finding a community that is willing to do this for you can make all the difference regardless of the type of goal you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: You say you were taking a break to study in your own. You tell them what you were studying, how you approached it, what worked, what didn't work, and what that says about your strengths and your potential value to their company

Comment: Note that the fact that you think the break was a mistake (or at least not as successful as you had hoped) does not invalidate your reasons for taking it. It just means you can explain the lessons learned that have caused you to shift your focus back to employee status instead, or in addition.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I've decided to do this and just be honest and use it as an opportunity to connect with some of the values they have as a company.

Comment: You may want to try and change your perspective: you didn't take a break, you studied and setup a company: both are (hard) work. Taking a break implies resting, taking vacation, doing nothing, but you didn't do nothing!

Comment: Hi Mark, wow, that is correct. I was self employed and upon reassessment saw that it'd have taken much longer to turn it into a full-time income and no certainty. I would love to be honest in the interview but i wonder if companies really want to hear about why  I AM returning vs why I am RETURNING.. ie., I'm returning coz I need money implying that I may not be serious about their company or job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you find something good soon!
The words you are using: intimidating, demotivated, drained easily... suggest some personal tendencies which are less common and so perhaps not understood by others or yourself. I'm not saying there's a 'diagnosis' or that something is wrong, just something to learn about yourself and how the world strikes you.

As a child I was often told to "come out of my shell", speak up, not be shy and things. For whatever reason - and again, not saying it is a 'problem' - I found the world rather loud and scary. Certainly I'm not extraverted, and I do care deeply about people and issues.

My minor study in college was psychology, because I was always wondering about people and their motivations, and myself and why I seemed different. There are lots of not really science approaches like Myers Briggs, the Enneagram and so on. If you look in to them as suggestive ideas and not the Answer, it can help. The most useful book I found was "The Highly Sensitive Person". That appears to have good science and good insights.

I have to remind myself that most people are actually caring, friendly and pleasant, and that one more phone call is not going to kill me. I don't know why that is my issue, but it hasn't gotten a lot better over my lifetime. If even one person "gets you"  that helps, but basically you'll have to push yourself up the hill and just try not to worry about it. I have labels for these tendencies, which helps me identify what I'm experiencing and move along.

There's nothing wrong (as far as I can see) and it just takes some self-awareness and persistence. Job hunting has to be one of the most unpleasant things that people routinely face. Good luck!

Comment: In a later comment to the question OP said that they had a very negative experience in prior job. So this counts as 'traumatic' and the approach would be similar but would benefit from a Therapist helping.

Comment: Thanks HI. I'm working with a counsellor and will continue to do so. I got a few call backs and I'm excited... Like someone said earlier first steps are always the hardest!!

Comment: This response was for my first question related to motivation. I've edited the question since then, taking feedback from the moderators to keep within the guidelines - Just wanted to clarify that if this response seems out of context, it's because the old question has been edited. But this was a great response at the time.

Comment: Thank you. Good question and answer, why are they downvoted? Upvoted for both.